# Windows 10 Home Network Error 0x80070035

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing

I have a network with 1 x W10 and 3 x W7 computers, all with network discovery turned on and file/printer sharing allowed. Until recently I have been able to access and share files successfully between all 4 computers, but in the last few weeks I have been unable to access one W7 machine from W10, although W7 can still access W10 OK; the other W7 machines in the network are not affected and files can still be read from W10. Switching off the Firewalls on both the machines in the faulty connection makes no difference.

I read in a blog somewhere that update KB4480970 can cause this issue so I uninstalled that update, again without effect.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

KB4480960 and KB4480970 both caused a problem with administrators accessing shares on Windows 7. Try uninstalling KB4480960, too.

Comment: Thanks Doug, but I ran SYSTEMINFO and neither of those two updates is installed on my computer